# How do I run DialogInput and SystemDialogInput by keyboard shortcut?

Tags: front-end, evaluation, customization, dialog-window

I have tried modifying `KeyEventTranslations.tr` with code:

```
Item[KeyEvent["r", Modifiers -> {Control}], 
    FrontEndExecute @ Module[
      {p ,ret},
      DialogInput[{
        ListPicker[Dynamic[p],{"one", "two"}], 
        DefaultButton[DialogReturn[ret = p]]
      }]
    ],
    MenuEvaluator -> Automatic, Method -> "Queued"
],
```

but it complains that

> DialogInput is not currently supported within preemptive evaluations

whenever I call the keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Maybe you could prompt a `MessageDialog` first and from there run whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks, however unluckily MessageDialog doesn't wait for input like DialogInput does.

Comment: Yes, I know but it can be some kind of intermediate step with a short message about what is going to happen and a "Queued" button to run your initial procedure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't run Kernel Blocking Dialogs on the preemptive link. But you can prompt other dialogs. And we can abuse that to run a procedure containing `Input[]`, `DialogInput[]` or some system dialogs.

**The trick** is to run your code inside an asynchronous initialization of the regular dialog:

```
MessageDialog[
   DynamicModule[{},
      1,
      Initialization :> (
         NotebookClose @ EvaluationNotebook[];

         (*put here a custom procedure*)

       ),
       SynchronousInitialization -> False
   ],
   Visible -> False
]
```

This regular invisible dialog is closed automatically by itself.

We can test it with `Button` as by default it uses preemptive link, just like procedures assigned to keyboard shortcuts.

Normally you wouldn't be able to run this procedure from there:

```
 procedure[] := Module[{test}, test = Input[];  Print[test]];

 Button["test", procedure[]]
```

> Input::nprmtv: Input is not currently supported within preemptive evaluations. >> (*after click*)

But with this workaround it works:

```
Button["test", 
 MessageDialog[
  DynamicModule[{}, 1, 
   Initialization :> (NotebookClose@EvaluationNotebook[];
     procedure[]), SynchronousInitialization -> False], 
  Visible -> False]
]
```

Comment: That's a really creative idea, but it doesn't solve my problem :/ I want to be able to use the return value of this Dialog box in another function which shouldn't run before the Dialog box is closed.

Comment: @Ranza The point is that instead of my `Module` you can use whatever you want, if your procedure contains another dialogs, doesn't matter,  it should work. Everything except the `Module` is just a wrapper here.

Comment: Stupid me! Indeed you're right, thank you a thousand-fold!

Comment: Very clever. This is really useful for things like auto-asking for a file name on a `"MouseEntered"` event or similar, too. One thing to beware of is that you really need to ask for `Evaluation*`  _before_ the `MessageDialog` pops up and adding it with `With` or something. I was just using this to auto-replace a label with a file name and ran into just that issue.

Comment: @MB1965 Thanks. Yes, many solutions are really tricks so one has to always be careful :)