# When I insert an if block into the ScheduledTask, I'm entering the password and the program is closing

Tags: conditional, api, email, url, scheduledtask

I'm new in Mathematica. So I'm unable to settle a matter. When I insert an if block into the ScheduledTask, I'm entering the password and the program is closing. What is my mistake? Can you help me please?

```
obj = SessionSubmit[
       ScheduledTask[
      If[URLRead[
     "https://api.archis.company/welcome", {"StatusCode", 
     "Body"}] == 
     <|"StatusCode" -> 200, "Body" -> "\"Welcome To ArchisAcademy API!\""|>, 
      SendMail["wlmailtest@wolfram.com", 
      "Here is the body of the message."]],
      {Quantity[1, "Seconds"], 30}]]
```

Comment: Did you try just `If[URLRead...` to see how your condition works? Also `===` would be more appropriate, and even more `MatchQ[ KeyValuePattern["StatusCode"->_] ]`.

Comment: Yes I have already tried and it's working.  Could the problem be on the schedule?

Comment: Why and where are you entering a password? Is a password dialog popping up when the scheduled task runs? Is that for the email? If so, I think you will need to eliminate the need of that interactive password dialog, I am quite sure that this will create problems within the scheduled task...

Comment: It's email's password for authentication.  So how can I log in without opening the password dialog?

Comment: How come it shows you the dialog, I am getting "AuthenticationDialog is not currently supported within preemptive evaluations." - message. Which can be worked around with: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/206416/5478

Comment: After setting it to "Enter Mail APP password automatically" it worked. Thanks to everyone who answered.

Comment: @seher: if the comments helped you to solve your problem and none of the commenters is willing to write an answer you can accept it is absolutely OK and very welcomed on this site to answer yourself. This will help others and probably also  is useful for you as a reference. If no other answers appear within some days, you can (and should) then even accept your own answer which will mark the question to be solved...

Comment: @AlbertRetey Yeap definitely. I'm quite pleased to solve my problem and I want to help the others too. Happy to be here...:)